После деплоя angular проекта на github pages получаю ошибку 404 chunk-7AJRLZ53.js
Я создал проект на Angular, написал .yml файл, все задеплоилось, но переходя по ссылке на сайт: https://nonestspes.github.io/leetCodeTest/
я получаю ошибку 404
перейдя по https://nonestspes.github.io/leetCodeTest/browser/index.html

а почему вы решили, что по первой ссылке веб-сервер github хоть что-нибудь найдёт для отображения? файла index.html в этом каталоге ведь вы не поместили. файл 3rdpartylicenses.txt, который у вас там лежит, отлично отображается: https://nonestspes.github.io/leetCodeTest/3rdpartylicenses.txt
